# Primefaces 4.0 datatable Filterby not filtering data

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I've got an orderBy to work, but my FilterBy does nothing.  Symptoms: No messages, and all rows still show up.  Neither the column's filter, nor the global filter work.  Sometimes typing in the filter box causes the table to reload in its original order (after a page refresh).

The project uses JPA 2.0, EJB 3.0, PrimeFaces 4.0, Facelets.  My UserDAO extends an abstract DAOService.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I've looked at the Primefaces 4.0 documentation, and the Primefaces website's DataTable filterBy example; I've also searched StackOverflow and google. I can't figure out where I've gone wrong.

xhtml page:

```
<!-- Define Facelet Template -->
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

<!-- Header defined in template -->

<!-- Body overrides template -->
<ui:define name="content">
    <f:view>
        <h:body>
            <h:outputStylesheet name="css/styles.css" />
            <p:dataTable id="dataTable" widgetVar="usersTable" var="user"
                value="#{users.all}" emptyMessage="none found"
                filteredValue="#{users.filteredUsers}" editable="true"
                editMode="cell" rowKey="user.id">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputPanel>
                        <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
                        <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="usersTable.filter()"
                            style="width:150px" />
                    </p:outputPanel>
                    <!-- <h:outputText>Users</h:outputText> -->
                </f:facet>
                <p:column id="idColumn" headerText="ID" sortBy="id"
                    filterBy="#{user.id}">
Edit: I have also tried filterBy="id" to no avail.
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.id}" />
                </p:column>
                ... more columns like that ...
                <f:facet name="footer">This is a footer</f:facet>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</ui:define>
<!-- Footer defined in template -->
</ui:composition>
```

UserController.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import model.security.dao.UserDAORemote;
import model.security.jpa.TSEC_User;

//Accessible to jsf page as "users"
@ManagedBean(name="users")
@SessionScoped
public class UserController implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EJB // // Injects the UserDAO session bean using the @EJB annotation
UserDAORemote model;

private List<TSEC_User> all;
private List<TSEC_User> filteredUsers;

public UserController() {}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    all = model.find();
}
public List<TSEC_User> getAll() {
    return all;
}
public void setAll(List<TSEC_User> all) {
    this.all = all;
}

public List<TSEC_User> getFilteredUsers() {
    return filteredUsers;
}
public void setFilteredUsers(List<TSEC_User> filteredUsers) {
    this.filteredUsers = filteredUsers;
}
}
```

Comment: Found the answer, but I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question.  My template.xhtml file used <head> and <body> tags instead of <h:head> and <h:body> tags.  Changing these to their JSF equivalents allowed PrimeFaces to filter my DataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My template.xhtml file used `<head>` and `<body>` tags instead of `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` tags. Changing these to their JSF equivalents allowed PrimeFaces to filter my DataTable.